# Как заменить все буквы в строке

Tags: php

Как заменить в строке все буквы `a` на `t`, а все буквы `t` на `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res = strtr($str, 'at', 'ta');
```

Где $str - нужная строка

Comment: спасибо работает, а то пытался через функцию а она меняет одну и следом другую